# How can I display DVD video, connected through a TV tuner, in full screen?

Tags: display, dvd, fullscreen

I have a 23" Dell LCD/LED monitor connected to a computer and a DVD player via a TV tuner.

Movies watched through the computer are displayed in full screen mode, but movies watched through the DVD player are displayed in cinemascope, which I don't want.

How I can set things up so that all movies are displayed in full screen mode?

The monitor has HDMI, DVI and VGA interfaces available.

Comment: Does the DVD player display fine when hooked directly to the monitor?

Comment: Be more specific: What computer, what graphics card, what DVD player, what TV tuner, what player do you use, which movies are you watching, et cetera.

Comment: And when you say 'Cinemascope' do you mean you're getting letterboxing? That very well could just be the settings on the DVD player...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just play the DVD using the computer - you won't get the quality loss and resolution munging that happens when the signal is converted to analog at the DVD player then back to digital at the tuner.

Of course if you want to stick with the DVD player and tuner option (so you can use a remote control?), then you should try changing display settings in your DVD player setup menus, and also options in your TV tuner software, which probably has similar settings.

DVD movies are normally in a 16:9 aspect ratio (1.78:1, typical widescreen) or even 2.35:1 (Cinemascope). If your monitor is also widescreen, 16:9 movies should have little or no black border; with 2.35:1 Cinemascope movies (which is most movies now days), it is normal to have black borders of maybe 20% of screen height above and below the video. This gives the video the same look as in a cinema.

If we are misunderstanding you, please give a diagram of your monitor, showing how much video there is with the DVD player/TV tuner vs movies played back directly on the PC.